# SMALL BOX Solution - To control/reduce power consumption in household electrical appliances?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply

We use multiple power sockets to power different house hold electrical appliances like.. AC, Refriegerator, Television and Other Electrical Appliances. I want to turn on/off their power supply/consumption during specific time of the weekday/end or when I am not in house.

1. A socket similar to female socket at home, that can be controlled/programmed based on the requirement like : 2-4 PM ON and then 4-6 PM OFF on any given day in a week.
2. It should be smart/intelligent switch in a SMALL BOX, so that it can be taken from one power socket to other power socket based on the user's requirement to control the power consumption in appliances A, B or C.
3. It should be user friendly enough so that a layman should be able to program the logic to turn on-off based on the requirement.
4. solution should be cost effective/efficient and durable.

Can anyone please help me suggest a design/solution to this?

I know it can be controlled/programmed through uC, but do not know about electronic circuit and its interface to uC etc..

Comment: Something like this: http://www.miniinthebox.com/programmable-lcd-digital-timer-power-adapter-ac-230v-3000w-max-uk-plug_p326884.html

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie my thought ;o)

Comment: If this meets my requirement to program the power usage, then it is excellent and this what I need. But I want to know the internal electronics design, microcontroller used, any other timer ICs, Transistors etc used and want to design on my own. Please help me in getting the circuitry please. Regards, Raminder Gujral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off **be very careful when dealing with [mains power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity)**! You can really hurt yourself or start a fire.

> I want to know the internal electronics design, microcontroller used,
>   any other timer ICs, Transistors etc used and want to design on my
>   own. Please help me in getting the circuitry please.

You can easily make one with a microcontroller, relay and several other parts (the most complicated part would be getting 3.3 or 5vDc, and that's not too tough.) I designed a similar unit for my work.

To get you started, you should look into using a simple microcontroller (MCU) board like an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) to keep the time and switch the relay (turn the outlet on and off.) It would be connected something like this:

[image]

The Arduino can keep the time fairly accurately (enough for this type of application, probably off by around 5 to 10 mins a year,) but you could use a real time clock IC if you want to be more accurate. If you're familiar with MCU's you can take a look at [Atmel's real time clock app note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc1259.pdf), it's a bit complicated if you don't know what your doing; and you don't need to go that route if you use the Arduino's software.

You would probably want a display and some buttons to see and set the current time, and on and off times. A 7 segment display (like in the picture below,) would work or you could even use a cheap LCD display like [this](http://www.miniinthebox.com/programmable-lcd-digital-timer-power-adapter-ac-230v-3000w-max-uk-plug_p326884.html) uses. However you can do without them if you just want to set it all on a computer via USB.

Another thing to consider is a battery backup to keep the time, and other settings saved would be nice too, however you can go without it if you want and you can save the time to the eeprom every 10 mins so that if the power does fail it will come back relatively close to the correct time. You don't want to save the time too often since eeproms have a limited amount of writing before they stop working (in an Atmel AtMega, I think it is ~100,000 times.)

Here are two walkthroughs on what's involved (2 links but the same project I think, I didn't read through to see if they are exactly the same or not though.) [Arduino controlled outlet](http://blog.chrisgilmer.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/Arduino-Controlled-Relay-Box.pdf) and [Controllable Power Outlet.](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/119)

Here's a picture of a similar device I designed for my work.

[image: Premier Systems Digital Timer PS-DT48M6]

(The processor and power regulation parts are under the 7 segment display.)

Comment: @RaminderGujral no problem, welcome to EE. There are a lot of devices like these, even mechanical ones. One thing I forgot to add is be very careful when dealing with mains power! You can really hurt yourself or start a fire. Also, if this completely answered your question you can click the check mark to the left of the answer (below the up/down arrows.)